# Site works in Safari but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, stylesheet, mozilla

Relatively newbie here. I have pulled my hair out trying to figure out why my site works in Safari but not in Firefox. My firefox browser is up to date. It is as if Firefox is totally ignoring the CSS style settings. I am sure the solution is SO very simple but since I have been staring at this for so long I'm sure I'm overlooking it.

Here is the HTML:

```
        <body>
        <div class="container">
            <article>
                <h1>//Onagus</h1>
                <p>Hallo and welcome to my site which is always a work in progress. I am using this site to showcase my web development skills as well as my other creative projects. Feel free to poke around and get a feel for what falls into my range of interest and experience.</p>
            </article>
            <div class="windowContainer">
                <div class="windowLine1"</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>News</h3>
                        <p>Sample Text</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Visit our blog</a></p>
                    </div>
                <div class="windowLine1"</div>  
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Visuals Blog</h3>
                        <p>Sample Text</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Read the article</a></p>
                    </div>  
                <div class="windowLine1"</div>  
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Media: Sound</h3>
                        <p>Sample Text</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>  
                <div class="windowLine2"</div>  
                    <div class="content">
                    <h3>Media: Video</h3>
                    <p>Sample Text</p>
                    <p><a class="cta" href="">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>  
            </div>
            <nav>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Music</a>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            </nav>

            <footer>
                &copy; Onagus 2014
            </footer>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS :

```
    @charset "UTF-8";

body {
    background: #fceecb;
    color: #e6eed9;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0px, auto, 0px, auto;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(../images/cabbitHouse1.jpg) #381f1a;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? What are you expecting? Would you please create a jsfiddle with your code so it will be quicker and easier to help you?

Comment: Your divs are poorly formed. And also... setting a DOCTYPE can be beneficial. It might break your page initially but go to this link to check for problems with your markup and solutions! http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try the jsfiddle and repost later. I see that the divs are not properly closed now.. Thank you guys!

Comment: Ok... So I tired closing the divs and that didn't work. Then I found out that in the css file, the type="text/css" was done incorrectly... I had typed 'txt' instead of 'text' and so I changed it and now it works! www.onagus.net/about.html   I am*so* relieved!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed. Browsers will attempt to fix it for you but may do this in different ways, resulting in different output. You should make sure that you site conforms to the W3C standard to ensure the most consistent and future prof output.

Here is a [parser](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) that may help you.

See this `<div class="windowLine2"</div>`. the div tag is not closed properly

```
<div class="windowLine2"</div>  
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Media: Video</h3>
        <p>Sample Text</p>
        <p>
            <a class="cta" href="">
                Learn more
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

you probably want this:

```
<div class="windowLine2">  
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Media: Video</h3>
        <p>Sample Text</p>
        <p>
            <a class="cta" href="">
                Learn more
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As Matthew said, your css also has an error with the way you declared the margin:

    margin: 0px, auto, 0px, auto;

It should be:

    margin: 0 auto;

No commas.

Comment: OK. I see now that the divs were not properly closed... Also... I will try to change the format to remove all the commas. Thank you!

Comment: @Toshi Great! I am glad that helped. On stack overflow if an answer helps you. It is good practice to vote it up or mark it as the answer to your question. This helps others find an answers to a similar question and motivates us to keep helping.